# databases query movie

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Singer

```
SingerId[pk]    SingerName  City    DOB Gender
1   A   Hyderabad   14-Apr-65   M
2   B   Chennai     25-May-84   M
3   C   Bangalore   14-Sep-78   F
4   D   Hyderabad   17-Jan-70   M
5   E   Hyderabad   18-Mar-87   F
6   F   Bangalore   23-Aug-75   F


MovieId[pk] MovieName   ReleaseDate
1   AAA 12-Jan-15
2   BBB 19-Sep-12
3   CCC 23-Jul-10
4   DDD 06-Oct-01
5   EEE 08-Nov-05
6   FFF 18-Apr-99
7   GGG 07-Aug-12
```

Performance

```
PerformanceId[pk]   SingerId[fk]    MovieId[fk] NumberofSongs
1   1   1   2
2   3   1   4
3   2   2   6
4   4   5   3
5   5   5   3
6   2   6   2
7   4   6   5
8   6   4   6
9   6   3   3
10  4   3   4
```

Q: List the Singer details, movie details, along with Number of songs

for the above requirement I tried below query::

```
SELECT  a.singer_id,a.singer_name,a.city,a.dob,c.movie_name,c.release_date,b.nof_songs 
FROM    singer a 
        INNER JOIN performance b 
            ON a.singer_id=b.singer_id 
        INNER JOIN movies c
            ON c.movie_id=b.movie_id
```

But not getting the exact result.
Please help me to find out the exact result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Singer.*, 
       Performance.nof_songs, 
       movies.movie_id, movies.movie_name, movies.release_date
FROM movies 
   INNER JOIN Performance ON movies.movie_id = Performance.movie_id 
   INNER JOIN Singer ON Performance.singer_id = Singer.singer_id
```